# docker-compose command is giving error while building

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am pretty amateur to docker. I was running my application on docker successfully from many days.

Now when I run the command **docker-compose up -d** it gives me the error as below

```
raceback (most recent call last):
File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 88, in main
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 140, in perform_command
File "compose/cli/main.py", line 900, in up
File "compose/project.py", line 385, in up
File "compose/project.py", line 590, in warn_for_swarm_mode
File "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 73, in info
File "site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 47, in inner
File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 179, in _get
File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 466, in request
File "site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 641, in 
merge_environment_settings
File "site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 605, in get_environ_proxies
File "site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 589, in should_bypass_proxies
File "urllib.py", line 1510, in proxy_bypass
File "urllib.py", line 1484, in proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf

ValueError: negative shift count
Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

I searched this error **ValueError: negative shift count** a lot but nothing useful found.

Comment: Can you show your source file `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: what is your `docker info` output? Did you use `docker swarm mode`? What is your `docker-compose.yml` file like?

Comment: Thanks for you help guys, but it get solved automatically, next day when I build composer it works automatically